# Include PHP file with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to include files with jQuery?

eg.

```
if browser width is > 999 

  include(OBJECTS_PATH."_ids/catalogue_slideshow_popup.id.php");

else

  include(OBJECTS_PATH."_ids/art_catalogue_popup.id.php");
```

Thanks!

Comment: you mean to include different js files? Or you mean to load different html content? The latter can only be done via ajax. PHP code cannot be run on client side

Comment: html content from the php file

Comment: then ajax is your only option

Answer (score 2):

No, not in the regular sense. PHP interpreters run on the server while jQuery runs on the client (browser) and has no knowledge of the server. So jQuery could technically fetch the code, but wouldn't understand it.

What you usually do is make the PHP server output something the client can understand, like HTML code (with or without JavaScript) or a json object which can then be used by jQuery.

(PHP is just a language so you could theoretically write a client-side interpreter, but there are most certainly better options for what you are trying to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is running in the client side of the application. So you won't be able to run a php script from the client side. If you want to load html content from the file then you can put a ajax request and load the file

```
$('#result').load(OBJECTS_PATH+"_ids/catalogue_slideshow_popup.id.php", function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should know javascript or jquery is client side and php is server side, So you won't be able to run a php file from the client side.

with jquery you can do this and you will get html content:

```
width = $(window).width();

if(width < 999){

    $.get('http://url.com/path/catalogue_slideshow_popup.id.php', function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    });

} else {
    $.get('http://url.com/path/art_catalogue_popup.id.php', function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: At least explain to him that javascript/jquery and PHP don't run on the same machine